# Raise event from second thread to main thread, without forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, invoke

I'm writing a library that is firing events. This library starts a second thread that is connecting to a server and listens for messages (blocking calls, reason for the second thread).

```
public virtual event LogEventHandler EntryReceived;

protected virtual void ReceiveEntry(ILogEntry entry)
{
    if (EntryReceived != null)
        EntryReceived(this, new LogEventArgs() { Entry = entry });
}
```

When a message is received from the server, it is firing an event :

```
ReceiveEntry(entry);
```

I'd like the end developper not to have to think about the InvokeRequired/Invoke snippet in his event handler. How could I ensure to fire my event on the "parent" thread (which I know is the same than the thread that did instantiate my class) ?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose have some winforms elements a property called `SynchronizingObject`. This property is of type [ISynchronizeInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) which has the needed methods to execute the call within the UI thread.

In your code you check this property for nullity and if it is set you use it:

```
var sync = this.SynchronizingObject;

if (sync != null && sync.InvokeRequired)
    sync.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> ReceiveEntry(entry), null);
else                        
   ReceiveEntry(entry);
```

The user of the library just has to put in a Control or a Form into that property:

```
private MyLibraryClass _MyLibraryClass;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _MyLibraryClass = new MyLibraryClass();
    _MyLibraryClass.SynchronizingObject = this;
    _MyLibraryClass.EntryReceived += OnEntryReceived;
}

private void OnEntryReceived(object sender, LogEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Text += e.Entry.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If during object Construction you capture the [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) you will be able to Send the events on that context if there is one, if there is no context then your class was constructed on a thread where it does not care which thread will be used to raise the event. This is better than `ISynchronizeInvoke` because `SynchronizationContext` will work with WinForms, ASP.NET, and WPF where  `ISynchronizeInvoke` only works for WinForms.

C# 6 version

```
public class Example
{
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    public Example()
    {
        var existingContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _context = existingContext?.CreateCopy() ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    }


    public virtual event LogEventHandler EntryReceived;

    protected virtual void ReceiveEntry(ILogEntry entry)
    {
        _context.Send(ContextCallback, entry);
    }

    private void ContextCallback(object entry)
    {
        EntryReceived?.Invoke(this, new LogEventArgs() { Entry = (ILogEntry)entry });
    }
}
```

C# 5 and lower version

```
public class Example
{
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    public Example()
    {
        var existingContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _context = existingContext != null ? existingContext.CreateCopy() : new SynchronizationContext();
    }


    public virtual event LogEventHandler EntryReceived;

    protected virtual void ReceiveEntry(ILogEntry entry)
    {
        _context.Send(ContextCallback, entry);
    }

    private void ContextCallback(object entry)
    {
        var temp = EntryReceived;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new LogEventArgs() {Entry = (ILogEntry)entry});
        }
    }
}
```